# Unable to delete cart item one by one and increment and decrement too

Tags: reactjs, cart

https://github.com/uttampun44/exclusivestore/issues/36

Here is the project link make Branch for issue

Product data is fetched from the Node.js product folder. When I click add to cart, it is added, but when I click remove from cart, it removes the whole item from the cart. Also, increment and decrement the items, not only one by one. Help me please. I am using the context API.

Comment: This isn't how Stack Overflow works.  You need to include a minimal reproducible example, as well as details on how you tried to fix the issue.  You need to include your actual code, not a link to a github issue.